# How prevent a function from being called on an active tab?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Example 1:

click on `tab1`. Tab 1 is active tab. Click again on `tab1`(tab1 is active tab) I don't want to call function `start()`. Click on tab 2 or tab 3 I want to call function `start()`.

Example 2:

click on `tab2`. Tab 2 is active tab. Click again on `tab2`(tab 2 is active tab) I don't want to call function `start()`. Click on tab 1 or tab 3 I want to call function `start()`.

Code here: https://codepen.io/kaka-milan/pen/YmXJJy?editors=1111

Drawing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksiwq.jpg

```
var Tab = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <li 
      className={ this.props.isActive ? 'navigation--active': '' }
      onClick={ this.props.onActiveTab }
    >
      <p>{ this.props.content }</p>
    </li>
  }
});

var Tabs = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { selectedTabId: 1 }
  },

  isActive: function (id) {
    return this.state.selectedTabId === id;
  },

  setActiveTab: function (selectedTabId) {
    this.start();
    this.setState({ selectedTabId });
  },

  start: function() {
    return console.log('aaa')
  },

  render: function() {
    var total = this.props.data.points.total,
        tabs = total.map(function (el, i) {
          return <Tab 
            key={ i }
            content={ el.name } 
            isActive={ this.isActive(el.id) } 
            start= {this.start}
            onActiveTab={ this.setActiveTab.bind(this, el.id) }
          />
        }, this);

    return <ul className="navigation">
     { tabs }
    </ul>
  }
});

const data = {
  points: {
    total: [
      { id: 1, name: 'tab-1', text: 'text' },
      { id: 2, name: 'tab-2', text: 'text-2' },
      { id: 3, name: 'tab-3', text: 'text-2' }
    ]
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Tabs data={ data } />,
  document.getElementById('main')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a condition to check whether the clicked tab is already selected or not, if it is already selected don't perform any operation else run it as normal

```
setActiveTab: function (selectedTabId) {
    if(!this.isActive(selectedTabId)){
     this.start();
     this.setState({ selectedTabId }); 
    }
  },
```

[`Demo`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PMqyLp?editors=0010)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add condition to check its not equal with current state tab :

```
setActiveTab: function (selectedTabId) {
    if(this.state.selectedTabId!==selectedTabId){//ensure only trigger when different tab id
       this.start();
    this.setState({ selectedTabId });
    }

  },
```

Here is [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NQqEqY)